# Abstract class inheritance and smart pointer containers

Tags: c++, inheritance, containers, smart-pointers

I am creating an abstract geometry class that has children classes. However, I want that the class `RightCircularCone` also has its own private variables that define its apex coordinates, such that the abstract class is not unnecessary big in memory size for objects of type `Sphere` that don't need storage of apex variables. 
However, I can't seem to access the functions and variables of `RightCircularCone` when I load them from a container that uses smart pointers, as it keeps being defined as its parent class `Shape`. Can anyone see what is going wrong?! Appreciate it!

```
/* shapes.hpp */
class Shape{
    public:
        unsigned int color;
        float radius;
        float x,y,z;
    public:
        void SetSpatial(float radius, float x, float y, float z);
        unsigned int GetColor(void);
        void SetColor(unsigned int color);
        virtual bool PointInside(const std::array<double,3> &point)=0;
};

class RightCircularCone : public Shape{ 
    private:
        float Ax,Ay,Az;
    public:
        bool PointInside(const std::array<double,3> &point);
        void SetApex(float x, float y, float z);
        void PrintApex();
};

class Sphere : public Shape{
    public:
        bool PointInside(const std::array<double,3> &point);
};
```

The classes defined above are used in another .cpp file where methods of a class are defined:

```
#include "../../include/part.hpp" /* includes shapes.hpp in turn */

void Part::ReadPartFile(std::string partfile){
    try{
        std::ifstream dataFile;
        dataFile.open(partfile);
        //do checks, error badbits etc...
        std::string word;
        unsigned int counter=0;
        while(!dataFile.eof()){
            dataFile >> word;
            if(word == "sphere"){
                auto newSphere = std::make_shared<Sphere>();
                // load variables into objects from file by checking each word by using setColor and setSpatial
                shapeList[counter++] = newSphere;
            } else if(word == "rccone"){
                auto newRccone = std::make_shared<RightCircularCone>();
                // load variables into objects from file by checking each word by using setColor and setSpatial and setApex
                shapeList[counter++] = newRccone;
            }
        }
        dataFile.close();
    } catch(std::ifstream::failure e) {
        //do exception handling here if necessary
}
```

Now, when I use an iterator over the map `std::map<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<Shape> > shapeList;` as defined in `part.cpp` I can never access the methods of children classes `Sphere` and `RightCircularCone` as the map returns a type of `Shape`, even though I used a smart pointer!!!
Anybody knows why and a potential fix (or neater way to set up the classes)??
Thanks!

//EDIT:

This is the error I get:

```
error: no member named 'PrintApex' in 'Shape'
                                iterator->second->PrintApex();
```

Comment: Again the common mistake, no checking of a stream extraction: `dataFile >> word;`

Comment: A smart pointer is not a magic wand. Why do you expect it do do magic stuff for you?

Comment: Well, smart pointers in a container do just that. At least, they should! Usually when you create a container of the parent class type you can store child class type in it such that when you extract it out of the container you can use the methods/vars of that child class, right?

Comment: They don't, they shouldn't, and you can't.

Comment: It would be easier to discuss the problem with your code if you show a line that produces compilation errors, and explain what in your opinion it should do. Also of you are replying to someone in comments, mention their name like this: @LoekJanssen.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for pointing that out! Run time error included.

Comment: That would be a compile-time error. So what you expect to happen if the shape stored at that place in your container is actually a sphere, a paraboloid, a knotty stringy shape, or a squiggly doughnut-like shape with three ears? None of them have `PrintApex` member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it. You create a vector of shared_ptr of Shape. As far as the vector is concerned you are storing Shape instances in it, not Sphere or whatever.

Now, you happen to initialize your Shape instance with a Sphere and you store the ptr of that Sphere into the vector. Next item is a RightCircularCone, again stored as a Shape.

You access the first element, and as far as the compiler is concerned at THAT point, you only have a Shape. It cannot deduce the actual type as this happens at runtime. So, as far as the compiler is concerned you have a Shape instance with whatever the Shape class contains.

Now, you need to somehow inform the compiler about the type you want to work with, so it can find the methods you want to access. For that, you use dynamic_cast to specify the intent that this is a Sphere and you should have access to Sphere members.

More details about dynamic_cast, here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Edit. A note about design.

In principle, you want to offload as much to the compiler. If there is something that compiler can do, let him do it. So, if you want to do something different for each subclass of Shape, instead of checking a string literal for the Shape type you could use virtual specialized functions that act on a specific type. E.g.

```
virtual void printMe(Sphere & sphere) {
cout << "This is a sphere with radious x" << endl;
} 

virtual void printMe(RightCircularCone & cone) {
cout << "This is a cone" << endl;
}

//and you use like 

for (auto & shape: shapes) { printMe(shape); } 

//and the correct functions are resolved automagically
```

it may seem a bit more work, but in the long run it is actually simpler as you offload the picking of the functionality to someone else.

Comment: Please do not suggest `dynamic_cast` to programmers that don't understand inheritance.

Comment: @n.m. That's why the reference to cppref. He should read this stuff

Comment: "Now, you need to somehow inform the compiler about the type you want to work with, so it can find the methods you want to access. For that, you use dynamic_cast to specify the intent that this is a Sphere and you should have access to Sphere members." Please don't suggest this solution to inexperienced people. It's simply bad engineering. cppreference won't tell you that, it's a C++ language reference. One needs a resource dedicated to object-oriented programming and design, not any particular language.

Comment: One wants to use a virtual function, exactly like suggest. Not because "you want to offload as much to the compiler", but because this solution is extensible and future-resistant (you don't need to open it up when you add new shapes) while the one with `dynamic_cast` is fragile.

Comment: @n.m. I agree with the bad engineering, that's why my edit with a more sound way of doing what he wants to do. He should get away from casting but right now he has to understand the what would be needed to move forward with what he has to do.

Comment: @n.m. Again, I agree, I just find appealing to laziness (at least in the beginning) a better driving force than benefits that may never be perceived. I'm sure you've heard this before "no, we won't have more than two classes, we don't need that".